# ASP.NET Dropdownlist: value of ddl.text becomes the value of ddl.selectedvalue in selectedindexchanged

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue, selectedindexchanged

ASP.NET 4.0 & SQL 2008

I would like to ask for help in my coding, I don't know what's wrong or what am I missing. 
What I want to do is when I select an item in `dropdownlist`, it will give me the ID `(ddlSchool.selectedvalue)` and the value of the text `(ddlSchool.text)`.

Below is the code that populates the dropdownlist. I'm getting the value of ID and Text from the database, it works perfectly fine; When I debug it, it gives the correct value of the ID `(newItem.Value = .dr("fnorglevelid"))` and the correct value of Text `(newItem.Text = .dr("fcorgcode").ToString()`

```
    Protected Sub populateDDLDepartment()

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim newItem As New ListItem()
        newItem.Text = "Select a Department..."
        newItem.Value = "0"
        ddlSchool.Items.Add(newItem)

        Try
            With connSchool
               .conn = New SqlConnection(.strCNN_ADMtoGRAD) : .conn.Open()
               .strSQL = "select fnorglevelid, rtrim(fcorganization) as 'fcorgcode'"& _
                            "from hris_organization " & _
                            "where flschool = 1 " & _
                            "order by fcorgcode asc"
               .cmd = New SqlCommand(.strSQL, .conn)
               .dr = .cmd.ExecuteReader()

                While .dr.Read
                    newItem = New ListItem()
                    newItem.Text = .dr("fcorgcode").ToString()
                    newItem.Value = .dr("fnorglevelid")
                    ddlSchool.Items.Add(newItem)
                End While

            End With
        Finally
            With connSchool
                .conn.Close()
                .conn = Nothing
                .strSQL = vbNullString
                .strSQL = Nothing
                .cmd.Dispose()
                .cmd = Nothing
                .dr = Nothing
            End With
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I select an item, the value of ddlSchool.text becomes the same as the value of ddlSchool.selectedValue. I put it in the message box first:

```
    Protected Sub ddlSchool_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlSchool.SelectedIndexChanged
         MsgBox("Text:" & ddlSchool.Text & "   ID:" & ddlSchool.SelectedValue)
    End Sub
```

What am I missing? What do I have to do? It seems that `selectedValue` is the same as Text.

Comment: can you try ddlSchool.SelectedItem.Text

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! It works. OMG that was dumb of me *facepalm* 

:D

Comment: no problem glad to help :), please mark felix's answer as correct cause it has the same asnwer

Comment: Research dropdownlist datasource, databind, datavalefield and datatextfield.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

**Value**

```
ddlSchool.SelectedValue
```

or

```
ddlSchool.Text
```

**Text**

```
ddlSchool.SelectedItem.Text for
```

thank you